# What is the number that shows up after you define an anonymous function in elixir?

Tags: elixir

When you define an anonymous function in elixir you get a result like this.

`#Function<6.90072148/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>`

What I've noticed is that the number is based on the arity of the function. So a 1 arg function is always

`#Function<6.90072148/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>`

A two arg function is always

`#Function<12.90072148/2 in :erl_eval.expr/5>`

A three arg function is always

`#Function<18.90072148/3 in :erl_eval.expr/5>`

What is the number that's being returned, and how is it being derived?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number consists of the index and a unique name of the function, which are generated by the compiler. Take a look at the [implementation of the inspect protocol for functions](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/25f64051ba6bc2fb4d98fca93496a38d3f84a9df/lib/elixir/lib/inspect.ex#L445-L487). It contains this passage:

```
"#Function<#{uniq(fun_info)}/#{fun_info[:arity]} in " <>
  "#{Inspect.Atom.inspect(mod)}#{extract_name(fun_info[:name])}>"
```

where `fun_info` refers to the result of a previous call to [`:erlang.fun_info`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#fun_info-1). This loosely translates to the following pseudo-code, where all interpolated values refer to elements of `fun_info`:

```
"#Function<#{new_index}.#{uniq}/#{arity} in #{module}.#{name}>"
```

As you have correctly observed, the part after the `/` indicates the arity. `module` and `name` show you where the function was defined. `new_index` is a pointer into the module's function table, and `uniq` is a hash value of the module  generated by the compiler. When you invoke `:erlang.fun_info` for a function, you will be able to recognize the values from the inspect string:

```
iex> fun = fn x -> x end
#Function<6.90072148/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

iex> fun_info = :erlang.fun_info(fun)
[pid: #PID<0.58.0>,
 module: :erl_eval,
 new_index: 6,
 new_uniq: <<171, 204, ...>>,
 index: 6,
 uniq: 90072148,
 name: :"-expr/5-fun-4-",
 arity: 1,
 env: [...]]
```

The uniq value and the index taken together provide a way to uniquely identify an anonymous function. Be aware that inside `iex` these supposedly unique values will be very similar for all functions you create, but when the code is "properly" compiled, they will be unique. Consider the following iex session:

```
iex> fn -> end
#Function<20.90072148/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex> fn -> end
#Function<20.90072148/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex> fn -> end
#Function<20.90072148/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
```

Now compare that to running the following file with `elixir fun.exs`:

```
IO.inspect fn -> end
IO.inspect fn -> end
IO.inspect fn -> end

# this prints

#Function<0.120576197 in file:fun.exs>
#Function<1.120576197 in file:fun.exs>
#Function<2.120576197 in file:fun.exs>
```

Comment: This is great. I thought maybe the numbers after the decimal were supposed to be unique, but I noticed they were the same not only for my session but for most of the sessions I came across on the internet, which was pretty surprising

Comment: Yes, it was pretty confusing for me at first, too. This happens because `uniq` is kind of a hash function over the module definition, which in iex is `:erl_eval` as you can see. `index` will also always be the same number because every time something is eval'd, the context is the same and the counter starts again from the same point.